# How to load a html template into the $scope?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to populate an `ion-content` container. I want to load HTML into the `$scope` depending on which tab the user clicks:

```
<ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only">
    <ion-tab ...>
    <ion-tab title="Create" icon-on="ion-android-create">
        <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
            {{getCreate}}
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ...>
</ion-tabs>
```

This is the controller for this view:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ionicApp')
        .controller('HomePageController', ['$scope', '$state', '$templateCache', HomePageController]);

    function HomePageController($scope, $state, $templateCache) {
        $scope.getCreate = function() {

            // at the moment create.html is just simple static html.
            return $templateCache.get('app/views/home/ads/create.html');
            //return $templateCache.get('main.create'); // this also doesn't work
        };
    }
})
();
```

The two relevant states are defined as:

```
.state('main.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomePageController'
        }
    }
})

.state('main.create', {
    url: '/create',
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home/ads/create.html',
            controller: 'CreateAdController'
        }
    }
})
```

Am I going about this incorrectly? What do I need to do to load `create.html` into `$scope.getCreate` in my `HomePageController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As raised by @Patrick Kelleter, your approach is overly complex including working manually with the $templateCache and compiling HTML.

Why not use the router the way it's designed?

First, rename the state's view so that you can reference it explicitly:

```
.state('main.create', {
    url: '/create',
    views: {
        'create': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home/ads/create.html',
            controller: 'CreateAdController'
        }
    }
})
```

Then change state using `ui-sref=` on the tab, and insert the state's template using `<ion-nav-view ...>` with the specially named view.

```
<ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only">
    <ion-tab ...>
    <ion-tab title="Create" icon-on="ion-android-create" ui-sref="main.create">
        <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
            <ion-nav-view name="create"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab ...>
</ion-tabs>
```

The router will then insert the content of `app/views/home/ads/create.html` into the `<ion-nav-view name="create">` element when the tab is clicked.

Here is a full walkthrough: [Build an App with Navigation and Routing - Part 1](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/)

Comment: this is *almost* perfect, except for the line `'create': {`. When I specify the view name create, it doesn't work but when I used `main` it did. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'm more familiar with `angular-ui-router` than the Ionic version. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

your approach seems a bit too complicated to me.
first of all you would have to make sure that your template has been loaded to $templateCache. this only happens when the template is rendered for the first time somewhere in the app (for example by using the "templateUrl" property)
alternatively you could fetch the data from the file by an ajax call on your own and compile it with the given $interpolate, $compile functions from angular. but then again: this seems way too complicated for this case.

secondly you would have to use ng-bind-html instead, because the way you did it there would be sanitized html to be seen. so there would be stuff like
 etc instead of a compiled html version of it.

probably you should simply use the ng-include directive instead and everything will be fine in a blink of an eye ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$http.get`:

```
   $http.get($scope.template.url).then (function(response) {
       console.log(response);
       $scope.contents = response.data;
   });
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/bYVXV4HkJp7O5lztM57T?p=preview).

The browser's [Same Origin Policy](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_XMLHttpRequest) and [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors) policy may restrict whether the template is successfully loaded.